# Astronomy in Middle-earth

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

There already are a number of [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2237/324) which discuss the relationship between "our world" and Middle-earth.

I am interested in the astronomy of Middle-earth, which I guess could possibly have discussed in some book. I am currently re-reading the LotR (I highly recommend to read it multiple times, and I feel to be not alone with this idea :) ) and am noticing a lot of nice details. Among these, there is this description at the end of *Three is company*:

> Away high in the East swung Remmirath, the Netted Stars, and slowly above the mists red
>   Borgil rose, glowing like a jewel of fire. Then by some shift of airs all the mist was
>   drawn away like a veil, and there leaned up, as he climbed over the rim of the world,
>   the Swordsman of the SKy, Menelvagor whith his Shining belt.

[Menelvagor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_cosmology) with his [Shining Belt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion%27s_Belt) could be [Orion](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Orion_3008_huge.jpg). This is consistent with the time of the year (autumn in the northern hemisphere). Is it possible to identify the other stars or planets? (Borgil, with a red hue, could be Mars).

Comment: Check out the references and speculation on [this website](http://valarguild.org/varda/Tolkien/encyc/stars.html).

Comment: I don't know much about astronomy but could "the Netted Stars" be the Pleiades?

Comment: I was just about to ask this question myself.  Happy/sad someone beat me to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_cosmology) has a good list of star references and more explicitly cross-referencing those with real life stars where provided.  Those specifically cross-referenced I've included below, along with citations where possible:

- Alcarinque - Jupiter? *(Morgoth's Ring)*
- Borgil - Aldebaran? *(A Definitive Identification of Tolkien's 'Borgil': An Astronomical and Literary Approach)*
- Carnil - Mars? *(Morgoth's Ring)*
- Eärendil’s Star, Gil-Amdir, Gil-Estel, Gil-Oresetel, Gil-Orrain - From *Letter 297*:

> Eärendil ... To my mind the A-S uses seem plainly to indicate that it was a star presaging the dawn (at any rate in English tradition) : that is what we now call Venus: the morning-star as it may be seen shining brilliantly in the dawn, before the actual rising of the Sun.

- Eksiqilta, Ekta - Orion’s Belt *(Qenya Lexicon, Parma Eldalamberon 12)*
- Elemmire - Mercury? *(Morgoth's Ring)*
- Helluin - From the *Silmarillion*:

> Helluin        The star Sirius

- Luinil - Uranus? *(Morgoth's Ring)*
- Lumbar - Saturn? *(Morgoth's Ring)*
- Menelvagor, Daimord, Menelmacar, Mordo, Swordsman of the Sky, Taimavar, Taimondo, Telimbektar, Telimektar, Telumehtar - Orion *(Lord of the Rings, your reference above)*
- Morwinyon - Arcturus *(Book of Lost Tales)*
- Nenar - Neptune? *(Morgoth's Ring)*
- Remmirath, Itselokte, Sithaloth - Pleiades *(Lord of the Rings, your reference above)*
- Valacirca, the Sickle of the Valar, Burning Briar, Durin’s Crown, Edegil, Otselen, the Plough, Seven Stars, Seven Butterflies, Silver Sickle, Timbridhil - Ursa Major / Big Dipper *(Lord of the Rings, allegedly, but I can't find this beyond deduction from the description)*
- Wilwarin - From the *Silmarillion*:

> Wilwarin  Name of a constellation. The word meant 'butterfly' in Quenya, and the constellation was perhaps Cassiopeia.

Comment: so Menelvagor, daimord etc are the names of the stars or synonims? Or is it a part-for-the-whole figure of speech?

Comment: Synonyms.  They are multiple names for the same constellation.

Comment: It might be possible that Durin's Crown was actually...Northern Crown, Corona Borealis.