# Where exactly does Eragon take place?

Tags: inheritance-cycle, geography

I'm doing an assignment for class about Eragon. I'm wondering about the setting. Is Alagaesia an island?

> "Do you  remember what I told you about how the elves came over
>   the sea?"
>    <sub>- page. 169</sub>

I know that this implies that Alagaesia was an unexplored continent, but it could also imply that it was an unexplored island. Then what about the map? It only shows part of the... setting. You don't know if it's a continent/big hunk of land or only an island. I guess that it makes *more* sense for it to be a continent, but I'm not sure. However, if there are any extremely careful readers, they might know. Thanks for the support!

Extra note: If it was a continent, there would be other people on it, even if unmapped. If the Empire doesn't explore the island/continent, then won't the other population/country explore and (might) invade the Empire?

Comment: All continents are basically islands, because at some point, they are surrounded by an ocean. The sheer size of them (like Australia, for instance), becomes so large that 'island' simply doesn't fit in common English usage, and continent has to be used instead.

Comment: @Singular1ty I guess, but as long as you (and other readers) understand the question, I don't get why that matters.

Comment: http://www.paolini.net/stuff/articles/article-series-christophers-art/map-alagaesia/ - Map

Comment: @Richard Cool, but it only repeats my question at the end lol

Comment: And don't forget: why don't the people outside the Empire somehow group together and invade it? In fact, the people most likely don't even know of the Empire. Until they send scouts and then...

Comment: @HengyuanZhang - Actually it answers your question nicely; 1 - Alagaesia = a continent. 2 = It stretches well beyond the border of the existing map eastwards. 3 = The author hasn't drawn anything beyond the wastelands.

Comment: Make it a post/answer

Comment: @HengyuanZhang - You do it. I'm off to bed.

Comment: Richard has so much rep he's just handing it out now :D

Comment: @Richard, HengyuanZhang: Jeez, have you guys not read the last book?

Comment: @Richard That's two crappy answers based on just copying your comment. Maybe people think quoting you magically gets them rep? :-P I mean, sure, I'm biased, but which of these 3 answers is the best, objectively?

Comment: @randal'thor -  Objectively yours is the best answer but I've upvoted Hengyuan Zhang's self-answer on the grounds that it directly answers his own question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### It's a continent, bounded by ocean on the west and  more land on the east, much like Europe.

Here's a map of Alagaesia:

[image: map]

North and south, and more importantly east and west, of this continent are all unknown territory. To the west is (as usual in fantasy novels) an unexplored ocean, possibly with other land on the far side. To the east is wasteland, beyond the Hadarac Desert, and finally inhabitable country. We know that this doesn't count as Alagaesia, and that it's inhabitable, because in the final book

> Eragon and Saphira fulfil the prophecy made by Angela in the first book and "leave Alagaesia for ever" to settle down in these unexplored lands far to the east.

In fact, Europe is a fitting analogy. In writing his novels, Paolini took a great many ideas from established fantasy authors such as Tolkien. Admittedly the geography of Alagaesia doesn't look *that* much like that of Middle-Earth, but it still has ocean to the west, wasteland to the east, elves in the forests, and dwarves in the mountains. A great many fantasy novels employ these tropes, and it all goes back to Tolkien ... who based his continent of Middle-Earth on that of Europe, as described in [this excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90972/31394).

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question: Alagaesia was most likely a continent (using logic). Here's why:

> 1 - Alagaesia = a continent. 2 = It stretches well beyond the border of the existing map eastwards. 3 = The author hasn't drawn anything beyond the wastelands.
>
> -Richard

Site: http://www.paolini.net/stuff/articles/article-series-christophers-art/map-alagaesia/

Using Richard's logic, Alagaesia should be a continent. I also agree with Richard.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>As @Richard pointed out,</sub>

Author Christopher Paolini offers [this information](http://www.paolini.net/stuff/articles/article-series-christophers-art/map-alagaesia/) on the map of Alagaësia.

### **Key points:**

1. Alagaesia is a continent
2. Alagaesia continues eastwards beyond the border of the map
3. The author *hasn't drawn anything beyond* the wastelands

[image]

Comment: To add to this, Paolini recently said that *The continent extends some bit farther north, but it's not considered part of Alagaësia proper.* ([Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/4i0tf1/hey_reddit_im_fantasy_author_christopher/d3k37t1?context=3))

Answer (score -4):

I would think that the Inheritance cycle took place in northeastern Africa.
I say this because the southwest slope of Africa and Alagaesia look very similar in this manner. There is also a similarity in the different types of habitats, like the deserts, grasslands, and forests. Those different habitats are also similarly placed.

The author, Christopher Paolini, also may have derived some of the names from the countries and cities, like the name of the continent, Alagaesia, and the name of of one of the countries, Algeria. Another similarity in names is Sierra Leona and Dras-leona, along with Leona Lake. As for the mountain ranges, he may have moved the Atlas mountains farther south for the Spine, and moved the Ahaggar mountains south for the Beor mountains.

Comment: Alagaesia is situated in a fantastic universe.
Also, there are no mild or cold climate forests in North Africa.

Answer (score -4):

I would venture to say that Alagaesia is an island like Australia. I would also venture to say that Alagaesia and Middle Earth exist in the same world. Much like LOTR, the elves traveled across the sea to the west. I want to believe that Alagaesia is south of middle earth, separated by an ocean above Du Wendelvarden. In my version of Elven history, two groups of elves traveled across Belegaer- The Great Sea (LOTR), and one group went south while the other continued forward. From there, the two groups evolved separately. Most of this is purely speculation.[image: Alagaesia]

Comment: I'm afraid pure speculation is not what we are looking for here.

Answer (score -4):

I am convinced that Alalia is somewhere south of Alagaesia with an ocean between them. In addition, beyond the Handarak dessert it may by other civilazations with humans, dwarfs or even, forgotten dragons. Now to the north, somewhere the Du Weldenvarden forest must end, and I imagine over there a volcanic place with lava mountains or a huge grassland like the land that Eragon and Brom crossed after the Udgarnd mountain. I can't imagine whats beyond the sea west of Alagaesia but it might be some islands like the Canarians somewhere over there.

Comment: But what is your support for this?