# What is the significance of Denethor eating the tomato?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-lord-of-the-rings

The scene in which Faramir is leading a battle and Denethor is eating the tomato while Pippin sings. What is the significance of that? Ostensibly it's to show that Denethor isn't interested or has already given up on his son, Faramir, but why was it shown that way in particular, with Pippin singing and the extreme close-up of eating?

Comment: That scene is quite a deep reveal of Denethor's character and position. I don't have the film studies skill for a full answer, but note that the tomato is probably the fanciest food seen in the trilogy.

Comment: My simple mind went "Tomato red, blood red; things not going well in battle"

Comment: "If you want a character to look like a-hole, show them eating as messily as possible. If you want to make him look like a huge a-hole, show them eating an apple."  https://www.reddit.com/r/CinemaSins/comments/2ynqju/so_why_does_eating_an_apple_make_you_look_like_an/ As for that specific reason: the guy is eating while people (including his only remaining son!) are dying. That casual indifference makes him a huge a-hole. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheSnackIsMoreInteresting

Comment: I don't have the time at the moment to pull it up and copy it down for you, but in the Extended Edition commentary, Peter definitely talks about that scene and why he shot it like that

Comment: Acidic tomatoes on pewter plates equals lead poisoning. The dude was nuts.

Comment: Apropos of nothing at all, I have to say that movie Denethor was about as far from book Denethor as he possibly could be.

Comment: Since [Middle Earth is prehistoric Europe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90972) this confirms pre-Columbian trade, for an Old World Steward to be eating a New World vegetable.

Comment: It's also weird in the sense that - who just eats a tomato?  I mean, not a cherry tomato but a large, full-sized tomato, just by itself?  Generally you'd cut it up into smaller pieces, slices, wedges, diced, etc.  Not many people would just take a big old bite out of the whole fruit.  It's particularly disconcerting watching someone do that.  One does not simply eat a tomato.

Comment: @jo1storm Also stuffing yourself on fresh fruit and vegetables _whilst in a city under seige_ is a dick move, even when people aren't dying.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Except it *is* a cherry tomato that Denethor is eating.

Comment: @Herohtar Is it?  I may have to re-watch - it's been a while, but I do remember him eating rather messily, with just juices all over his face, hard to do with a cherry tomato.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You can find some screen caps with a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=denethor+tomato&tbm=isch). There are also [clips of the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU7NXI7FmFQ) if you want to actually watch it. D:

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### It shows how deranged Denethor is

> Peter Jackson: I remember we came up with the idea of the eating during this, too, because there's something very nasty about eating and violence, you know? And a sense of violence, a sense of killing his own son while shoving strawberries and tomatoes into his mouth and it's just, I don't know, it's something that—
>
> Fran Walsh: It's cracking, and spitting, and—
>
> Philippa Boyens: Yeah, the tomatoes, ugh.
>
> Fran Walsh: It's very venal.
>
> Peter Jackson: Yeah.
>
> Philippa Boyens: It is.
>
> Peter Jackson: It's a bit uncomfortable— I think, you know, it makes the audience more uncomfortable, the fact that he's stuffing things into his mouth, than it would be if he was just sitting in the chair doing exactly the same dialogue. It's sort of the fact that he is sort of enjoying— because usually in situations like this, when there's life and death situations and it's war and it's, you know, a huge threat, you would lose your appetite, and the fact that he's sitting there kind of eating, even that helps sort of show how deranged he is and how sort of disconnected from it all he is.
>
> <sub>*The Return of the King Extended Edition* - Director's Commentary [1:32:31-1:33:32]</sub>

Comment: +1 for getting every "sort of" but the one in the title :)

Answer (score -1):

### The Red Tomato Pulp Represents Blood

The movie was rated PG-13 in the United States for its battle sequences, preventing them from showing as much blood and gore as some of Peter Jackson’s earlier movies.  This scene made striking use of visual symbolism, music and lyrics to represent the decadence of both Denethor’s lifestyle and the lives he was wasting.

Peter Jackson significantly altered the character from the books, in order to add this scene.  In the books, Denethor II was described as “a man of another sort, proud and subtle,” whose lifestyle is almost ascetic (his chair is “black and unadorned” and his chambers “sparsely furnished”).  Neither is there any scene in the books where Denethor asks a Hobbit to sing for him.  [This was added by screenwriter Phillipa Boyens, after hearing Billy Boyd sing at a karaoke bar.](https://fantasytopics.com/pippins-song-the-edge-of-night-lyrics-meaning/)

It is worth noting that Peter Jackson made the decision to adapt Tolkien’s “A Walking-Song” from chapter 3 of *Fellowship of the Ring*, by removing all lines about making it back “to home and bed,” and altering the line “Away shall fade, away shall fade,” from the middle of the song, into the closing line, “All shall fade, all shall fade.”  [Boyd, who was asked to write his own music, wrote several different Celtic-style melodies for the song,](https://youtu.be/fDQZOSo333Q?t=111) and they chose one as different from the festive drinking-song before as they could get.  This changed the song into a melancholy dirge, fitting the intended meaning of the scene.

**Edit:** This answer has turned out to be controversial, because it doesn’t cite any source for this interpretation.  Honestly, that was because I thought the scene speaks for itself.  A great many other people have observed that the tomato pulp running down Denethor’s chin, as his callousness sends his men riding to their deaths and Pippin sings of death, looks just like blood.  There’s no hidden reference that needs explaining.  You can see it with your own eyes.  It looks that way to you, or it doesn’t.

Comment: Is there a real source for this idea? If so, please edit your answer and add it on.

Comment: @CaptainJamesT.Kirk i appreciate your giving me a comment to explain the downvote. Since at least a couple of other people seem to agree with you: I’m not sure what you would consider “a real source.” Should answers on this site only repeat what the creators themselves have publicly said they meant? Or are you thinking it should have a Wikipedia-like policy of quoting only notable sources? Or something else? Literary interpretation is inherently opinion, not factual.

Comment: Two things: 1.- `Literary interpretation is inherently opinion` that's right unless there's an official statement from the writer/creator/someone that actively participated in the creative process, which in this case there is; and 2.- your answer seems more like a factual statement rather than an opinion, as it declares why the director shot the scene like that, and not why YOU interpreted it like that.

Comment: I've cleaned the comments here and [moved them to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135548/discussion-on-answer-by-davislor-what-is-the-significance-of-denethor-eating-the) as the discussion was getting quite long and somewhat going in circles plus an edit has been made to improve the answer. If you want to carry on the discussion please use the chat linked, [the meta that spurred off from here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13654/58193) or try and add something new.