# How many Men were there on Arda at the time of War of the Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, statistics

Is there a good estimate (books or supplementary canon material) of how many Men there were on Arda at the time of the War of the Ring?  I am OK with an answer either for Arda as a whole, or at least for the principal countries involved (Gondor, Rohan, Mordor, Easterlings).

<sub>NOTE: Whilst I've read the books and done some preliminary research, I can't pin down a figure for the number of men in Arda (or any of the other regions). To be honest, I'm just curious, but I think it might help me phrase another question</sub>

Comment: Related meta discussions: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2236/1027 & http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2237/1027

Comment: I would suspect that no census was ever done on the fictional planet.

Comment: @Chad - Arda is not fictional. It's supposed to be an "alternate past Earth".

Comment: @DVK - ... so you are claiming that lord of the rings is actually a work of non-fiction?  A documentary?

Comment: @Chad - leaving aside that I can name some "documentaries" that have more fiction than LOTR, no, what I'm claiming is that since it's meant to represent Earth N years back, the approach of approximaiting the population using archeological Earth data is not implausible nor invalid.

Comment: @DVK - Then I would suspect that you could get the answer better on History than Sci-Fi if you are looking for a real world answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no good canon estimate that I have been able to find. I will try to be well reasoned and suggest that since TLOTR is set [in our universe(ish)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22034/is-tolkiens-middle-earth-in-our-universe/22035#22035), and Tolkien has given a date of [about 6000 years in the past](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/in-what-time-period-does-the-lord-of-the-rings-take-place-in-the-real-world/2244#2244), we could go off of population estimates for that time period.

If we were to look at the [Fourth Millenium BC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4th_millennium_BC) we find that the population was about 7 million.

As an aside, it is rather sobering in an era that has seen the likes of Stalin, Hitler and Mao killing tens of millions apiece, to think that 6000 years ago there were only about 7 million of us.